# Assigning data to attributes and static attributes directly in c#

Tags: c#

I have a method as follows which gets data and stores them to specific variables. I also have two static variables that preserves their value if a condition is met. My question is how can I store this data in attributes in a specific class ?

Like for example, I have a class called `UserDetails` with attributes : 
**UserDetails** class

```
public class UserDetails {
    public static string RateCountry { get; set; }
    public static string RateWeek { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Second Class**

For now, its working like this. But I want to enhance it by making use of objects.

```
public static string RateCountry { get; private set; }
public static string RateWeek { get; private set; }

public ActionResult ShowList()
{   
    int start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]);
    int length = Convert.ToInt32(Request["length"]);
    string name = Request["search[value]"];
    string address = Request[("columns[3][search][value]")];
    string rateType = Request[("columns[7][search][value]")];

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rateType)) // if null, reset the static variables to null
{
    RateCountry = "";
    RateWeek = "";
}
else
{
    if (CheckDate(rateType)) // if contains date, assign to RateWeek
    {
        RateWeek = rateType;
    }
    else
    {
        RateCountry = rateType; // else if contains a string word, assing to ratecountry
    }
}
var items = AssignDetails(start, length, name, address, RateWeek, RateCountry);

return items;
}
```

Then instead of passing several parameters like `start, length, name` etc. in the method `AssignDetails`, I can pass an object of the `UserDetails` class directly taking into consideration the static variables.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: What you want to do really ? I think it is not clear

Comment: *properties*, not *attribute*. They do not mean what you think they mean.

Comment: Yes properties. Sorry.

Comment: @Aria : I want to make use of objects. 
Like `UserDetails user = new UserDetails {

Start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]), 
}`

Comment: *“I want to enhance it by making use of objects”* – Moving static members to a different type does not enhance anything. Static members are the opposite of “making use of objects”.

Comment: I am using the static variables to preserve the value.

Comment: It is no different where you define `static` variables, static is static .

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Note: In C#, they are called properties not attributes. [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) are a totally different thing.</sub>

What you want to do is straight forward:

Firstly, you need to change your method so it accepts your class `UserDetails` as an argument:

```
public void AssignDetails(UserDetails userDetails)
{
    // Use userDetails here to do whatever you want
}
```

Secondly, when you call the above method, you need to pass the argument to it. You can create an instance of `UserDetails` and pass it to the `AssignDetails` method:

```
var userDetails = new UserDetails 
{
    Start = start,
    Length = length,
    Name = name
    Address = address
}
```

I am not sure why `RateWeek`, and  `RateCountry` properties are `static` in your class, but to set those you can do them as below (Please note it is using the class and not the instance of the class):

```
UserDetails.RateWeek = RateWeek;
```

Comment: I am using them as static to keep their value. Like if one first execution of this methof, this returns true :: if (CheckDate(rateType)) // if contains date, assign to RateWeek
    {
        RateWeek = rateType;
} 

one second execution, the above is not true, but I want to preserve the value it had on its first execution.

Comment: How can I pass the `UserDetails.RateWeek` to `AssignDetails(userDetails)`

Comment: You do not need to pass it. Because it is `static`, you have access to it from anywhere you want. So in the `AssignDetails` method, you just access it like this: `UserDetails.RateWeek`. You need to be sure of how `static` works or you will end up in trouble. What do you mean by `first execution`?

Comment: Its an ajax call to the `ShowList()`. On first execution, I get `rateType` as 12/03/2018. 

On second execution, that is when I hit a option value component, I get `rateType` value as `ARA`. So I want to preserve the value of `12/03/2018` also.

Comment: Ok, then you should be fine. Please note that `static` stuff, such as `UserDetails.RateWeek` will stay that way until you change it or if you restart the application pool.

Comment: @ExpertGenie Is second `ajax` to different action, or all requests are to `ShowList()` ?

Comment: The second `ajax` points to the the same `ShowList()`. Actually its a data table implementation using pagination and filtering on server side. 

Thanks for your help. It works like you explained :) 

Yeah as you can see above, I am changing the value of the static `UserDetails.RateWeek``based on certain condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the instance's properties as an indirection to the class' static properties, although all this thing is really ugly in terms of design.

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public static string PersistedRateCountry { get; set; }
    public static string PersistedRateWeek { get; set; }

    public static string RateCountry
    {
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(rateType) ? "" : PersistedRateCountry; }
        set { PersistedRateCountry = value; }
    }
    public static string RateWeek
    {
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(rateType) ? "" : PersistedRateWeek; }
        set { PersistedRateWeek= value; }
    }
    public static string RateWeek { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I strongly suggest you to move these static properties out to another class, which would be responsible for persisting them.

E.g. try to separate your Data Object (which just holds data) from your Business Object (which contains business logic, and is constructed by receiving a Data Object as parameter). Put all that crazy persistence logic in the Business Object, and use the Business Object everywhere in your code (instead of using the Data Object).

Keep your classes short and clean. If you are coding a lot in the same class, it's probably because you got a bad object-oriented design.